# Design problem with android

Tags: java, android, xml, design-patterns

[image]

Little confused with the design in android..suppose i need to position two blocks

as in the figure..what shall i do?..if we use pixels the design looks different in different phones.

Design should be fixed in all phones..but how without using px we can design as above

Comment: Use dip instead of pixels and the attributes wrapcontent and fillparent are device independent

Comment: dip positions changes according if we change 5.1 in WVGA to 2.1QVGA or anyother...that should not happen for good design and can you show how we r gone use wrap content and fill parent for the above

Comment: My suggestion would be to try avoiding the Symbian way and using layout to fix your UI 'too' tightly to screen size. Let it adjust, just make sure it doesn't adjust too much. [Providing Alternative Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) is a good start IMHO once in need to start dealing with different screen sizes/densities etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use two **LinearLayout** in your layout xml and set **layout_marginLeft,layout_marginTop,layout_marginRight in dip** according to the need.

See the following layout, its very similar to the one you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button 
        android:text="Button01" 
        android:id="@+id/Button01" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
        ></Button>

        <Button 
        android:text="Button02" 
        android:id="@+id/Button02" 
        android:layout_below="@id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
        ></Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: dip positions changes according if we change 5.1 in WVGA to 2.1QVGA or anyother...that should not happen for good design

Comment: I have posted some code above that is very similar to your need . Just see it.

Comment: no its right in case of 2.7inQVGA ...check ur code 10.1inWXGA...button1 will be almost near to button2

Comment: If you are using relative layout and setting the margin between them realtive to each other i.e. for lower button **android:layout_below="@id/Button01" android:layout_marginTop="140dip"**

This will work.

Comment: One  thing you can do  is set this layout for the lower button : **<Button 
  android:text="Button02" 
  android:id="@+id/Button02" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_marginBottom="80dip"
  android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
  ></Button>**

Answer (score 0):

You could generate the layout in Java by getting the screen size and placing two objects (defined in xml or java) into the parent layout, taking into account the ratios.

Comment: get me an example for this image

Answer (score 0):

If dip is unable 2 solve ur problm , surely any of these approaches will work :

1) take a 9patch backgroud with proportionate padding . now put first textview with gravity left|top and  second with grvity right|bottom . done

or

2)Take two child of a vertical linearlayot with layout_weight=1 , so will each will take 50% height now to put put textview center vertical . now lets try fix it horizontally.4 each text 
take  two child textview with layout_weight=1 ,put text center_horizontal .for upper text male second invisible n for lower make first one invisible ......